# Почему высскакиает ошибка /bin/sh: 1: npm: not found Error response from daemon?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, docker, docker-compose

Только начал изучать docker, хочу обычный html файл запустить через tomcat используя docker.Работаю в IntelliJ IDEA.Там открыл пакет с проектом где есть этот html файл, в самом корне создал Dockerfile

```
FROM tomcat
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["tomcat","index.html"]
```

Как я понимаю мне должно на платформе tomcat на 3000 порту открыть файл index.html, но место этого мне выдает ошибку: Step 4/6 : RUN "npm" install
---> Running in aa9968fa65a1
/bin/sh: 1: npm: not found
Error response from daemon: The command '/bin/sh -c "npm" install' returned a non-zero code: 127
Failed to deploy 'my-container-2 Dockerfile: Dockerfile': Can't retrieve image ID from build stream

Уважаемые знатоки подскажите что я делаю неправильно? Почему эта ошибка выскакивает?

Comment: Потому что image tomcat не имеет на борту NodeJS! Перед тем как запускать npm install нужно установить в виртуалку NodeJS+NPM

Comment: Официальный tomcat основан на "java:8-jre", тот в свою очередь основан на Debian. Как ставить NodeJS на дебиан есть в этой статье https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md А именно нас интересуют команды:

`sudo curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | bash - && sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`